# Google Oauth not accepting Heroku app URL

Tags: heroku, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to install oauth2.0 for heroku app below is my url

```
https://some-url-60411.herokuapp.com/
```

It does not accept the URL, instead the google console says: `Invalid Origin: domain must be added to the authorized domains list before submitting.`

Could anybody let me know what's wrong here?